# Nightwatch. Click on element in first div with condition in second div

Tags: javascript, css, nightwatch.js

I have two div on my site:
:

```
<div class="wg-block"  data-reactid="10"
  <div class="wg-header" data-reactid="11"/div>
    ....
     <h4 class='condition'>  "Text" </h4>
  <div class="wg-footer" data-reactid="12"/div>
    ....
      <div class="click"> </div>
```

I need to click on element in the second div, a condition which is on the first div.

How can I correct click on this element?

Comment: You can use the e.target inside your function call.

Comment: Can you show us the nightwatch code?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a CSS selector.

```
browser.click('.wg-footer .click');
```

That selector would select all elements with class "click" that are inside the element with class "wg-footer".

The link below is a great resource for selecting elements with CSS.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp